# How can I remove irrelevant strings shown when \includegraphics command is used with grffile package?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I have read the following posts on this site:
[How to avoid showing the filename when using graphicx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/how-to-avoid-showing-the-filename-when-using-graphicx) and [Include figure from PDF file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145993/include-figure-from-pdf-file/146040#146040), but havent had any luck following the answers posted in the questions.

I am using `\includegraphics` to bring in figures and the file locations for the figures are showing up with the figures when I compile the PDF.

A working example:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

%preamble - set document settings

%package for loading images
\usepackage{graphicx}

%package needed for setting graphicspath with spaces in directory name
\usepackage[space]{grffile} 

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{{S:/Adv/Scallop Central/Logos/fullcolorlogo}.png}

\end{document}
```

I have also tried the following:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{{"S:/Adv/Scallop Central/Logos/fullcolorlogo"}.png}


\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{"S:/Adv/Scallop Central/Logos/fullcolorlogo".png}
```

but the PDF did not compile.  There was a warning that the image couldn't loaded because it is not a recognized file format.

When I do get the image in the PDF it looks like:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Did you try `{"S:/Adv/Scallop Central/Logos/fullcolorlogo.png"}`?

Comment: Why is the `.png` outside? I've never seen anyone do that `"...." ` Ln the entire file name should be enough. Best if course is to never use spaces in folder or file names

Comment: The answer below is why - it is from one of the two other answers above \usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{{"../Current folder/1.This file"}.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Comment: Yes I did try {"S:/Adv/Scallop Central/Logos/fullcolorlogo.png"} and got the same error message.

Comment: Another answer has this: \includegraphics{{example2.2}.png} - which also didnt work.

Comment: with pdflatex `\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{"S:/Adv/Scallop Central/Logos/fullcolorlogo".png}` should work (although not having spaces is better and not having the full path makes the document more portable) so `\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{fullcolorlogo}` would be best.  If you are using latex+dvips then it can not include png files. This form should work just with graphicx, you don't need grffile

Comment: I just tried your code and got the following: File "S:/Adv/Scallop Central/Logos/fullcolorlog".png not found.  The file directory is a long standing directory used by many and cant be changed.

Comment: Put `\usepackage{grffile}` before `...graphicx`. I'm not sure that this is necessary here, but my advice stems from using the pdfpages package. If pdfpages is loaded before grffile, grffile doesn't work.

Comment: I have tried all suggestions and even renamed my directory to exclude spaces.  The only way I can get the image to show up is with this \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{S:/Adv/Scallop Central/Logos/fullcolorlogo.png}
and the file directory still shows up.  At this point its easy to make a word document.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried with no `"` and `{}` like below?

`\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{S:/Adv/Scallop Central/Logos/fullcolorlogo.png}`

I have tried with below code and it worked, but it does not worked when quotation marks are included.

> **UPDATE**
>
> I got similar result as above answer with XeLaTeX. The filename disappeared when I compiled with pdfLaTeX.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}

\title{test}
\author{tester}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    test
    
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{/Users/j/Desktop/Screen Shot 2019-01-30 at 11.40.38.png}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]